# Data types of dynamic allocation pointer and pointer variable

Tags: c

Can anyone clearly explain (with examples) why do we have to change the data type of a dynamic allocation pointer from the default void type into the same data type of its corresponding pointer variable?

ex:

```
int *ptr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

Comment: [We don't and we shouldn't](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/69809).

Comment: Answer is in the duplicate, which will reveal to you that the assumption in your question is not correct. In short, **don't** cast in C, in C++ you need to.

Comment: @Bathsheba: in C++ you first need to wonder why you're using malloc :-)